# Column lines in DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I used `DataGrid` Control in my `WPF` project - that it has some columns. I want that, lines between Columns to be drawn till end of `DataGrid`, even if it doesn't have any rows.

```
<DataGrid Height="200" Width="200" BorderThickness="4" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="aa" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="bb" />
        </DataGrid.Columns></DataGrid>
```

can u help me what to do?